# Is trailing white space is forbidden in s-expression?

Tags: ocaml, s-expression

When I try *sexplib*, it tells me

`Sexp.of_string " a";;` is correct.

`Sexp.of_string "a ";;` is wrong.

---

Is trailing white space is forbidden in sexp?

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to an informal grammar specification, whitespaces should be ignored on both ends of an atom:

> {2 Syntax Specification of S-expressions}
>
> {9 Lexical conventions of S-expression}
>
> Whitespace, which consists of space, newline, carriage return,
>   horizontal tab and form feed, is ignored unless within an
>   OCaml-string, where it is treated according to OCaml-conventions.  The
>   semicolon introduces comments.  Comments are ignored, and range up to
>   the next newline character.  The left parenthesis opens a new list,
>   the right parenthesis closes it again.  Lists can be empty.  The
>   double quote denotes the beginning and end of a string following the
>   lexical conventions of OCaml (see OCaml-manual for details).  All
>   characters other than double quotes, left- and right parentheses, and
>   whitespace are considered part of a contiguous string.

Indeed, you can read an atom with a trailing whitespace from a file without any errors.

The error is thrown from a function `Pre_sexp.of_string_bigstring` in a case when a parser successfully returns, but something was left in a buffer. So the main question is why did something has left in the buffer. It seems that there exists several parsers, and files and string are parsed with different parsers.

I've examined `parse_atom` rule defined at `pre_sexp.ml:699` (all locations are for [this commit](https://github.com/janestreet/core/commit/5e75cb802b19818b09cbf587ff088e2ba5b63649) ) and discovered that when the trailing whitespace is hit, the `bump_found_atom` is called. Then, if something is on stack, the position indicator is incremented and parsing continues. Otherwise, parsing is finished, but the position is not incremented. With a simple patch this can be fixed:

```
diff --git a/lib/pre_sexp.ml b/lib/pre_sexp.ml
index 86603f3..9690c0f 100644
--- a/lib/pre_sexp.ml
+++ b/lib/pre_sexp.ml
@@ -502,7 +502,7 @@ let mk_cont_parser cont_parse = (); fun _state str ~max_pos ~pos ->
     let pbuf_str = Buffer.contents pbuf in \
         let atom = MK_ATOM in \
     match GET_PSTACK with \
-    | [] -> Done (atom, mk_parse_pos state pos) \
+    | [] -> Done (atom, mk_parse_pos state (pos + 1)) \
     | rev_sexp_lst :: sexp_stack -> \
         Buffer.clear pbuf; \
         let pstack = (atom :: rev_sexp_lst) :: sexp_stack in \
```

After this patch, the following code produces an expected `'a', 'a', 'a'` output:

```
let s1 = Sexp.of_string " a" in
let s2 = Sexp.of_string "a " in
let s3 = Sexp.of_string " a " in
printf "'%s', '%s', '%s'\n"
  (Sexp.to_string s1)
  (Sexp.to_string s2)
  (Sexp.to_string s3);
```

Comment: so you think it is a bug? should I report to the git repo?

Comment: @JacksonTale, looks like. Why not?